# Error converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that pulls accruals. We recently added a new "floating holiday" and I am unable to pull it. It was easy before, the code for the different accruals were coded as single numbers. They set the new one up as a letter and I cant pull anything now. Below is my code before the letter accrual. I am a total SQL newbie I will add, the below code took me about  a month to produce.

```
select 
    prec_emp as 'Employee ID',
    case 
        when prec_type = 2 then 'Sick'
        when prec_type = 1 then 'Annual'
        when prec_type = 3  then 'Personal Holiday'
        when prec_type = 6  then 'Comp Time'
        when prec_type = 4  then 'Holiday Banked'
        /*when prec_type = 9  then 'Covid Vaccine Personal Holiday'*/
        else null 
    end as 'Time Off',
    convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101) as 'Date',
    prec_avail as 'Hours',
    'Y' as 'Import Balances Reflect Taken',
    'N' as 'Import Balances Reflect Scheduled',
    'N' as 'Import Balances Are Added To Authorized'
from 
    prempacc
where 
    prec_active = 'Y' 
    and prec_type in (1, 2, 3, 6, 4)
```

Comment: The letter code theyre pulling is 'F' but i cant even get this to pull anymore because im getting a conversion error

Comment: Is "accrual" AKA "prec_type"? Replace `1` with `'1'`, `2` with `'2'`  etc. so it doesn't get converted from string to number

Comment: No idea what you mean by `code` in this question. The error message is telling you that some value is attempting to be converted to an int and the value in your table is not convertable to an int. Given your code I suspect that the datatype for the column prec_type is some sort of character? And recently a new value was added that is no longer a number?

Comment: Aside, you should not be using string literals for column aliases, use double quotes or the SQL Server specific [square brackets] if you need to delimit them.

Comment: What is the table definition of your table?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it from your question, prec_type is the VARCHAR column. If that's the case then changing your code to the following should allow it to run and add in your new floating holiday.

```
select prec_emp as 'Employee ID',
case when prec_type = '2' then 'Sick'
when prec_type = '1' then 'Annual'
when prec_type = '3'  then 'Personal Holiday'
when prec_type = '6'  then 'Comp Time'
when prec_type = '4'  then 'Holiday Banked'
when prec_type = 'F' then 'Floating Holiday'
/*when prec_type = '9'  then 'Covid Vaccine Personal Holiday'*/
else null end as 'Time Off',
convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101) as 'Date',
prec_avail as 'Hours',
'Y' as 'Import Balances Reflect Taken',
'N' as 'Import Balances Reflect Scheduled',
'N' as 'Import Balances Are Added To Authorized'
From prempacc
Where prec_active = 'Y' and prec_type in ('1','2','3','6','4','F')
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Deirdre I attempted the way you edited the code. I still get an error saying there was an error converting value 'F' to data int type

Comment: Just updated my code as I forgot to include the 'F' in the WHERE clause. However if you got an error regardless with the above statement, then I doubt that's the problem. What type of object is prempacc?  A table or a view?

Comment: prempacc is a table. If i do a basic select all from prempacc it will return numbers and the F. this particular query i have though errors regardless. Like I said, I am a newbie trying to learn....

Comment: No worries, we were all new at this stuff at one point. As Sean Lange asked, what's the definition of the prempacc table? Scripting this out (e.g. from SSMS) and editing your original question to add it may help you get a better answer than my attempt.

Comment: I asked ChatGBT and it said I need to use cast before the case. Im going to try that.

Comment: Guys I'm a total idiot and i apologize. Stu gave me the right advice, just putting my numbers in ticks as well as the letter F, everything worked.